Dev Container in VS Code using Docker Desktop when opening existing repo: SSH auth not working
/Edit: Think I found the issue. The SSH Agent that comes with Windows 11 when you install the optional SSH Agent is not compatible with newer SSH clients, i.e. the one that comes inside my dev container, see known issues
After I disabled the Windows 11 SSH Agent feature & installed v8.9.1.0p1-Beta (64 bit MSI) from here, it suddenly worked.

Windows 11
Docker Desktop
WSL2 enabled
Repo cloned before

Running Windows 11, and have set up a dev container, and trying to forward my local SSH keys (from my Windows machine) to the Dev Container.
Based on this post and this documentation I've enabled the SSH Agent feature on Windows 11.
When, I've added the key I already had in C:\users\user.ssh using ssh-add
When running ssh-add -l in both the host as well as the dev container, it seems to show up
Host:
ssh-add -l
3072 SHA256:ebwJvukNCOC21lw9yIiR8nhjkCEW/Voj/5mhsp/cSko user@DESKTOP (RSA)

Dev Container:
ssh-add -l
3072 SHA256:ebwJvukNCOC21lw9yIiR8nhjkCEW/Voj/5mhsp/cSko user@DESKTOP (RSA)

But, when I run git pull it tries to user publickey and thus fails.
I think it's because I cloned the repo on the host before with a different SSH Key, and the .git directory in the repo is pointing to that SSH key.
Many of other SO posts are using Ubuntu as host, whereas I'm using Docker Desktop + WSL2, as I've got a docker-compose file that has all the dependencies etc.
This is all very confusing, I just want to be able to re-use my Windows SSH keys inside my dev container.
It works fine if I re-clone the repo into the container, but I'd like to be able to reuse the already cloned repo as sometimes I work in it from the host.
